# IE quirks mode making page render strange - LI elements not horizontal

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, quirks-mode

I'm having a strange issue with quirks mode in IE 8. I'm working on a web page that is supposed to be rendering a horizontal menu bar. In FF and IE normal mode, it renders perfectly. However, when I set IE to quirks mode, the li elements of the UL render vertically and I'm not sure how to fix it.

Here is the CSS:

```
#primaryNav {
    background:url(/images/sprite_primary_nav.gif) repeat-x; 
    border:1px solid #dfdfdf;
    clear:both;
    height:49px;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:985px;
}
#primaryNav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin:0;

}
#primaryNav ul li {
    border-left:1px solid #dfdfdf;
    display:list-item;
    float:left;
    height:49px;
    padding-bottom:0px;  

}
#primaryNav ul li a {
    border:1px solid #ffffff;
    color:#333333;
    display:block;
    font-family:ScalaOTRegular, "Times New Roman", Arial;
    font-size:123.1%;
    height:32px;
    padding:15px 23px 0px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#primaryNav ul li a.afterActive, #primaryNav ul li a.firstNavItem {
    border-left:0px;
}
#primaryNav ul li.active a {
    background:url(../images/sprite_primary_nav.gif) repeat-x 0px -49px;
}
#primaryNav ul li:first-child {
    margin-left:41px;
}
#primaryNav ul li:last-child {
    border-right:1px solid #dfdfdf !important;
}
.primaryNavLast {
    border-right:1px solid #dfdfdf !important;
}
```

Here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content=""/>
    <meta name="keywords" content=""/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/reset.css" media="screen"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/delta_screen.css" media="screen"/>

    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="primaryNav" class="addShadowShadowPrimaryNav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Etiamn</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Integer</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Rhoncus</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sagittis</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Facilisis &amp; Inte</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!--end primaryNav-->
<!-- end scripts -->
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas? Thanks!!

Comment: why would you *want* to go into quirks mode? you've got a doctype, so you clearly don't *need* to be in quirks mode.

Comment: I thought doctype would correct the issue. However, all of the IE8 browsers I test with render it incorrectly, as if they are in quirks mode already. If I use F12 dev tools on my dev box and force it to render IE8, it's fine though.

Comment: is it definitely going into quirks mode? I can't see any reason why it would do so. It might be IE7 compatibility mode -- that's quite a common 'gotcha' issue, as there are some browser settings that can cause it to switch modes without telling you, particularly when you're viewing the site on your local network.

Comment: Yep. 'Use compatibility mode on intranet sites' was set. Unchecked and it works great. Put it as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it definitely going into quirks mode? I can't see any reason why it would do so.

It might be IE7 compatibility mode -- that's quite a common 'gotcha' issue, as there are some browser settings that can cause it to switch modes without telling you, particularly when you're viewing the site on your local network.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Doctype to strict. Their are some cases where transitional is in quirks mode while strict is not. Also check if anything is directly above the Doctype (even comments) and remove them.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are on an intranet and IE automatically will fall into a compatibility mode unless you tell it to otherwise.  Use the `X-UA-Compatible` header (or the equivalent `<meta>` tag) should fix the issue:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```